# C - MSVS 2013 "C2374: 'names': redefinition, multiple initialization" - why?

Tags: c, visual-studio, initialization, redefinition

Why does MSVS refuse to compile the following?

**config.h**

```
char *names[][2] = { 
    { "Marry", "McBlith" }, 
    { "Nadja", "Nurales"}
};
```

**main.c**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "config.h"

int main()
{
   printf("TEST (names[0][0]): %s\n", names[0][0]);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1>c:\projects\test\config.h(2): error C2374: 'names' : redefinition; multiple initialization
1>c:\projects\test\config.h(2) : see declaration of 'names'
```

**Error List:**

```
Error 1 error C2374: 'names' : redefinition; multiple initialization c:\projects\test\config.h 2 1 test
```

Why does **MSVS 2013** tell me its a multiple initialization when the array `names[][2]` is only declared and initialized once in `config.h`?

What am I doing wrong and what do I have to change to get this working?

Greetings

Comment: Do not put definitions in header files. You are probably including this file in another source file and linking the object with your program.

Comment: Are you missing `#pragma once` at the top of your `config.h`? It's better to put this in the code file rather than the header.

Comment: Yes I'm including this file in another sourcefile. I'll try putting it in the code file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put *definitions* in header files, then you will have those definition in all translation units that include the header file.

Instead have only a *declaration* in the header file:

```
extern char *names[][2];
```

And then put the definition in one source file.

Also, you might want to have [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file, to protect it from being included twice in a single source file.

Comment: zwei Leute - ein Gedanke

Comment: Thank you, I thought one could just have the .h file to keep it simple. Works with splitting it up into source and header.

Answer (score 0):

in an IDE like VisualStudio you have the optional addition to say, which header files to use, without #include'ing them (in gcc, that would be an optional parameter to the call), so may be including the header file twice.

this is normally ignored by including

```
#ifndef __CONFIG_H__ 
#define __CONFIG_H__
#endif
```

but normally you never define anything in a headerfile, just decalre things

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes I'm including this file in another sourcefile. I'll try putting it in the code file though.
```

This is what you are doing mistake with out having Header guards. You are including many times.

Use [Header Guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).
And in your source files declare using `extern`